# How to get value from combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I can't get value from `ComboBox` in WinForms using C#.

I have a `ComboBox` populated with a list of values and I have set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`.

Now, I have to find the value of the selected `ComboBox` item and select the matched item in UI.

Here is what I mean:-

I loaded the `ComboBox` like this :-

```
var list = (from l in db.Loc
            orderby l.LName ascending
            select l).ToList();
list.Insert(0, new Loc { ID = "-1", Name = "--Select--" });
cmb1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
cmb1.DataSource = list;
cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Now on an event, I am trying to match value (`ID`) and select the item. It's easy if I match `Text` property:

```
cmb1.Text = data.Name;
```

But How to match the value?

Something like this:-

```
cmb1.Value = data.ID;
```

Comment: The datasource is bound to the combobox, you can access your data directly through the combobox datasource. Could you explain a little more what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
cmb1.SelectedValue = data.ID;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only know the ID of the item you can also use:

```
cmb1.SelectedValue = data.ID;
```

Comment: I think no need to `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

`data` must be in the `list` binded to the `combobox`, then:

```
cmb1.SelectedItem = data
```

or, if it's not (you retrieved another instance from somewhere):

```
cmb1.SelectedValue = data.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to assign you "matched" value to the ComboBox Value property?
As soon as you have correctly set DisplayMember and ValueMember and you DataSource implements both as properties the values will be autoamatically "matched", e.g. you can read the Value property in you event handler to get this "matched" value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `cmb1.Text = text;` changes the text of the `ComboBox` to the specified value. It doesn't select the item with the text that matchs the specified value.

Use `cmb1.SelectedValue = value;` to select the item with the speciefied value.

Comment: I guess using the text property to select the item from the list would also just work.
I used that in worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index using `Combo1.SelectedIndex` property. You can get the item using either `Combo1.SelectedItem` or `Combo1.Items[Combo1.SelectedIndex]`